# Flutter Fitting Image in Box

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to get the image to fit, but no matter what I change, it has a gap to the right of the image. This is shown in yellow on the attached image.
[image]

My code is as below:

```
        child: Container(
          key: ValueKey(statusProvider.albumItem!.id),
          width: statusProvider.mainContainerHeight * .5,
          height: statusProvider.mainContainerHeight * .5,
          //padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          margin: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.teal,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20), // Adjust the radius as needed
            boxShadow:  [ BoxShadow(
              color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.9), // Shadow color
              spreadRadius: 2, // Spread radius
              blurRadius: 2, // Blur radius
              offset: const Offset(2, 2), // Offset in the x, y direction
            ),]
          ),
          child: Column(
            //mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            //crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Text(statusProvider.albumItem!.getDisplayDate(), style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 18),),
              statusProvider.albumItem!.pictureFile! == null 
                ? const Image(image: AssetImage('assets/img/missing_picture.png'), fit: BoxFit.cover,)
                : ClipRRect(
                  //borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                  child: Container(
                    color: Colors.amber,
                    child: Image.file(
                      //width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * .4,
                      //height:MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * .4,
                      width: statusProvider.mainContainerHeight * .4,
                      height: statusProvider.mainContainerHeight * .4,
                      statusProvider.albumItem!.pictureFile!, 
                      fit: BoxFit.fill
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
```

Comment: Try removing the width on Image.File

Comment: Tried that it still has the gap, but it the container fills the parent widget.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of wrapping with size, you can wrap with `Expanded` widget and use `fit: BoxFit.cover`.

```dart
Column(
  children: [
    Text(...),
    Expanded(
      child: ClipRRect(
```

Comment: I will try tomorrow and let you know.